# Find most common value in numpy 2d array rows, otherwise return maximum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like this

```
Nbank = np.array([[2, 3, 1],
                  [1, 2, 2],
                  [3, 2, 1],
                  [3, 2, 1],
                  [2, 3, 2],
                  [2, 2, 3],
                  [1, 1, 3],
                  [2, 1, 1],
                  [2, 2, 3],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 1, 1],
                  [2, 3, 1],
                  [1, 2, 1]])
```

I want to return an array with only one column. The condition is to return the most common value in each row; if multiple values have the same number of occurrences, just return the maximum of them.

I used this code

```
most_f = np.array([np.bincount(row).argmax() for row in Nbank])
```

if multiple values have the same number of occurrences, it returns the first item instead of the maximum. how can I work this around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will solve the problem.  You could probable make it into a one liner with some fancy list comprehension, but I don't think that would be worth while.

```py
most_f = []
for n in Nbank: #iterate over elements
    counts = np.bincount(n) #count the number of elements of each value
    most_f.append(np.argwhere(counts == np.max(counts))[-1][0]) #append the last and highest
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Counter after sorting in descending order by row.  There's a `most_common` that will return what you want.  Since it's sorted already, the first element is always either the largest or the most frequent.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
Nbank = np.array([[2, 3, 1],
                  [1, 2, 2],
                  [3, 2, 1],
                  [3, 2, 1],
                  [2, 3, 2],
                  [2, 2, 3],
                  [1, 1, 3],
                  [2, 1, 1],
                  [2, 2, 3],
                  [1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 1, 1],
                  [2, 3, 1],
                  [1, 2, 1]])


np.array([Counter(sorted(row, reverse=True)).most_common(1)[0][0] for row in Nbank])
```

Output

```
array([3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Question is whether the API for the counter object promises that `most_common` will do a stable sort (as opposed to happening to do so in the current implementation).

Comment: @alani Should be fine https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat a little bit and reverse each row in order to make `np.argmax` return indice of the rightmost occurence which corresponds to the largest item:

```
N = np.max(arr)
>>> [N - np.argmax(np.bincount(row, minlength=N+1)[::-1]) for row in Nbank]
[3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

You might also like to avoid loops which is definitely adviseable if you want to take full advantages of `numpy`. Unfortunately `np.bincount` is not supported for 2D arrays but you can do it manually:

```
N, M = arr.shape[0], np.max(arr)+1
bincount_2D = np.zeros(shape=(N, M), dtype=int)
advanced_indexing = np.repeat(np.arange(N), arr.shape[1]), arr.ravel()
np.add.at(bincount_2D, advanced_indexing, 1)
>>> bincount_2D
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 0]])
```

And then repeat the process for all the rows simultaneously:

```
>>> M -1 - np.argmax(bincount_2D[:,::-1], axis=1)
array([3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
```